# Getting \seq_show:N to print to the PDF

Tags: expl3

Could someone explain to me what's going on here? Why doesn't `\seq_show:N` produce any output?

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_test

\seq_put_right:Nn \l_test {a}

\begin{document}

\seq_count:N \l_test % returns 1, as expected

\seq_show:N \l_test % returns nothing

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\seq_show:N` prints to the terminal and to the `.log` file.  If you are running LaTeX from an editor you have to open the `.log` file to see

Comment: I get The sequence \l_test contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.13 \seq_show:N \l_test
                         % returns nothing
?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik OK, got it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\seq_show:N` prints to the terminal and to the `.log` file (`\seq_log:N` prints only to the `.log`), but doesn't produce any typeset output.  If you are running LaTeX from an IDE (that usually hides the terminal output) you have to open the `.log` file to see the output:

```
The sequence \l_test_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {a}
>  {b}.
```

That said, you can easily mimic the behaviour and make a function that typesets the contents of the sequence:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_test_seq

\seq_put_right:Nn \l_test_seq {a}
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_test_seq {b}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \mjc_seq_print:N #1
  {
    \seq_if_empty:NTF #1
      { The~sequence~\token_to_str:N #1~is~empty. }
      {
        The~sequence~\token_to_str:N #1~contains~
        the~items~(without~outer~braces):
        \seq_map_inline:Nn #1
          { \\ >~\use:n { ~ } \char`{~ ##1 \char`}~ } .
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_count:N \l_test_seq % returns 1, as expected

\seq_show:N \l_test_seq % returns nothing

\par

\noindent
\texttt{\mjc_seq_print:N \l_test_seq} % returns nothing

\end{document}
```